# Check opacity by jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, opacity

How do I check if the opacity of an element is 0, and then do something in jQuery?

Answer (score 68, accepted):

Have you tried using [.css()](http://api.jquery.com/css/)?

```
if($('elemFoo').css('opacity') == 0) {
    doSomething();
}
```

Comment: Anyone know the JavaScript equivalent

Answer (score 2):

You can do as

```
$(function() {

    if ($('#foo').css('opacity') == 0)
        alert('lol');

});
```

Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/9GEZ5/

Comment: @ggregorie, that will set the opacity to 0. The poster wants to check if the opacity is 0. The way to get the value is to mentioned in other people's answers.

Answer (score 1):

```
if( $("#id_of_your_thing").css('opacity') == "0" )
  do_stuffs();
```

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> var currentOpacity = jQuery.fx.step.opacity
>
> if(currentOpacity == 0)
> {
>    ...
> ```

Answer (score 0):

To find opacity you do

```
var x = $('#test').css('opacity');
x==0 ? alert('opacity is 0') : alert('Opacity is not 0');
```

### Check working example at http://jsfiddle.net/SCHNc/1/

Comment: I can't find the working example, can you make the text bigger?

Answer (score 0):

```
jquery.support.opacity
```

on jQuery 1.7.1 seems to work